# Animate background color with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to animate a `div` element when a button is clicked using a function. But, it doesn't work. What may be the problem?

JS:

```
function caller() {
    $("#hfont1").animate({
        "background-color": "#efbe5c"
    }, 1000);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="hfont1">Test Stuff</div>
<button id="bid" onclick="caller()">Hit me!</button>
```

CSS:

```
#hfont1 {
    color:#e8a010, font-size:48pt;
}
```

Example is linked here : http://jsfiddle.net/GELTP/1117/

**Update :** I know the way of using selectors but the question is why it is not working when `function _______` is used?

Comment: The function caller is not in scope. Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/edXfg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're defining the function inside of another function, not the global scope. If you switched from `onload` to `no wrap<head>` or `no wrap<body>` it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/GELTP/1121/

It would be even better if you switched from onclick to a javascript event binding.

Answer (score 1):

I took `onclick="caller()"` out and instead put in `$('#bid').click(caller);` into the jQuery bit. This does the same thing and achieves the result you like. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/GELTP/1118/

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error `-->` `Uncaught ReferenceError: caller is not defined`

You need to define your function before using it in onClick

select `No Wrap -in<head>` on your fiddle

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/GELTP/1120/

Answer (score 1):

The function caller is not in scope because the jsfiddle wraps it inside `window.load`

```
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
  function caller() {
    $("#hfont1").animate({"background-color":"#efbe5c"}, 1000);
   }
});//]]>
```

Try changing the option to `No wrap in Head` in jsfiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/GELTP/1124/ <<

Answer (score 0):

Your function is never getting called.  In JSFiddle, the scope of the html is not the same as the JavaScript, so calling 'caller()' will not call the variable you set up.  [Here's a working updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/GELTP/1122/) where you attach the action from JavaScript instead (which is normally considered best practice anyway).

```
function caller() {
    $("#hfont1").animate({"background-color":"#efbe5c"}, 1000);
}

$('#bid').click(caller);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle is to blame, the script is set to "onload" in the settings on the left, set it to "No wrap in <head>" and it works